# nodemon not working properly

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I am running my nodejs app by `npm start`

I just installed nodemon by 
`sudo npm install -g nodemon` so that i can get my server restarted when i save changes to files.

But when i try to start the server, something like this

`nodemon ./app.js localhost 3000 or nodemon start localhost 3000`

I get this as output

```
LM-SJC-00871929:webapp gdeep$ nodemon ./app.js localhost 3000
28 May 23:34:30 - [nodemon] v1.1.1
28 May 23:34:30 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
28 May 23:34:30 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
28 May 23:34:30 - [nodemon] starting `node ./app.js localhost 3000`
```

but when i go to my webpage, i get

`Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3000`. What am i doing wrong?

App.js here http://collabedit.com/t35dy

Comment: Your issue is likely not with nodemon.  Post the contents of `app.js`

Comment: I just added app.js  as part of the question. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Any luck? I have the same issue, 'starting' but not working

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You're running express 4, which has the `app.listen` call in a different file than `app.js`.  The command you're looking for is `nodemon bin/www` (`localhost` and `3000` are not needed in this scenario).

In fact, you can even run `nodemon` with no args, and it'll read what command needs to be run from `scripts.start` in `package.json` (which express generates automatically).

Comment: If you try to run the express app with just node and not nodemon, you'll get the same error. Since express 4, the script that runs the server is actually in bin/www (note there's no .js extension). This www file reads your app.js *config* and runs the server.

Comment: Also worth adding that you can run express 4 based apps just using `nodemon` with no args, because it'll red from the package.json file and run the `scripts.start` option.

Answer (score 25):

Here's what I did to make nodemon update correctly:

```
nodemon index.js -L
```

The `-L` flag stands for *legacyWatch*, here's an explanation from the official doc:

> In some networked environments (such as a container running nodemon reading across a mounted drive), you will need to use the legacyWatch: true which enables Chokidar's polling.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I had to install nodemon **globally**. Use this command to do so..

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

If you're using **Linux** you may need to prefix the command with the sudo keyword for administration access..

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 8):

try running `nodemon ./app.js  3000 or nodemon start 3000`

Comment: This doesn't fix his problem.

Comment: yes it doesn't. @SomeKittensUx2666, are you facing same problem too?

Answer (score 6):

1. `npm i nodemon`
2. Edit your `Package.json` file:- set start to `nodemon`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
}
```

3. Run `npm start` to try the server

Answer (score 5):

For Express.js 4, 
use nodemon

or
  nodemon bin/www

Answer (score 5):

Add following code in your code

1. `app.js`

   ```
   app.listen(3000, function(){
       console.log("info",'Server is running at port : ' + 3000);
   });
   ```
2. `package.json`

   ```
   nodemon app.js
   ```

Then run `npm start` from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using express4, the easiest way is to navigate to package.json and change

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First install nodemon by `npm install nodemon` or any command from the official website (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)
Then start your nodemon by `npx nodemon filename.js`
or if you have your `package.json` with you and the entry point is the file you would like to open then you can also go with the command `npx nodemon`
[Check this once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oufgf.png)

Hope it works!!

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

For Express 4; Just run

> nodemon

command (with out any args) on the directory; this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

thanks 
you need to type this after to enter in the folder application with

cd your_project_folder

`sudo nodemon bin/www`

Answer (score 0):

Certain child processes related to your parent process may not be closed. Try to kill all the child processes.

Ref: https://github.com/remy/pstree

Answer (score 0):

Use `single quotation` for multi-value args like `--exec'.

e.g. I changed `"nodemon --exec yarn build-langs"` to `"nodemon --exec 'yarn build-langs'"` and worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
```

check it, if it's true or not

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the command `nodemon start` to start your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on terminal if you are using Nodejs & TypeScript

```
npm i --dev nodemon ts-node
```

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions don't work for you and you have Node.js 18 or higher installed, you no longer need to use nodemon. Instead, you can pass the `--watch` flag and Node will automatically restart the server for you:

```
node --watch index.js
```

**Note**: the `--watch` feature is experimental.

Answer (score -1):

You might also run into the issue of having an empty `.nodemonignore`.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

and then
in
`package.json file`
keep like this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

instead of npx nodemon, which takes more time

Comment: There are other answers and a accepted one that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, **uninstall** `nodemon`:

`npm uninstall nodemon`

After uninstalling the `nodemon` then **install** `nodemon` globally using:

`npm i -g nodemon`

It will install `nodemon` **globally** then run the following command:

`nodemon index.js or app.js`